# How to disable "Reset Firefox..." button pop-up at Firefox browser startup

Tags: firefox

How to disable "Reset Firefox..." button pop-up at browser startup? Have investigated a lot, but haven't found how yet.

Have investigated if a config line in config file

```
c:\Users\<user123>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile234>.default\prefs.js
```

does it, but found nothing yet. I have to disable the pop-up in a non-default profile, i.e.:

```
c:\Users\<user123>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile456>\
```

I want that button pop-up to never happen. It would be really cool to also understand what triggers this pop-up, and how to handle the behaviour.

Up to now I found that *sometimes*, with some profiles it pops-up when you don't open the browser for 2 months, and then you open it.
Sometimes it pops-up, sometimes not, really crazy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the address bar and enter `about:config` then hit enter.

Right click anywhere and create new boolean `browser.disableResetPrompt` and set it to true.

Hope this helps

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot yoyo!
Even with somewhat older firefox releases.



Is there a place where all about:config configurations are explained/documented?
I searched for something like that, mozilla.org documentation and 
mozillazine.org regarding this, the closest I found:

[link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)
but that config is missing

Could you share where did you get that config?
Thanks!

Comment: http://miroslav.suchy.cz/blog/archives/2014/05/13/how_to_disable_reset_prompt_in_firefox/index.html   the first link on google when you search for "disable reset firefox"  I do not know where you could find all the possible entries that you can put in about:config... I will search more.

Comment: Your google first result, unfortunately not mine :( --
I searched/googled a lot, and that link didn't appear, very strange how google works.

Comment: Yes... even me I get different results if I search in different browsers. I think they track what you searched until now take that into account when building the search results.